# Web Server Log Analysis Tool

Tags: analysis, logging

Any suggestions for an accurate Web Log analysis tool to generate reports on the IIS logs? We used WebTrends, but I don't feel it was accurate.

Comment: From another comment, you said that you were analyzing a specific set of URLs.  How did you configure the profile, and what makes you believe that they aren't correct?

Comment: In web analytics, reporting accuracy is affected by a variety of things.  Most commonly: tracking method, filtering, and pageview definitions.  

We run our IIS logs through Angelfish, which offers a bunch of config settings for increasing accuracy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To analyze weblogs, I don't think you can go wrong with Analog: http://www.analog.cx/

If you are analyzing your own logs, which are often huge files, you will want the fastest analyzer you can find. Analog is fast.

You'll want one that's been around awhile and is still supported. Analog just celebrated its 10'th birthday.

Analog claims to be the most popular logfile analyser in the world.

Multi-languages.

Did I say its free and open source?

As far as accuracy goes, no tool gives perfect results. Javascript fails often in catching hits. Trying to track individual people's paths through a website (i.e. for Analytics purposes) is fraught with problems. And even trying to differentiate hits versus visits and screening out the bots is all more of a black art than a science.

What is best is simply to have a tool that gives decent basic statistics that tell you what you need to know.

I've looked at other tools, such as Deep Log Analyzer: http://www.deep-software.com/, which attempts to do analytics from your weblogs. But speed was a problem. They claim their new version 3.5 - April 2008, which I didn't try, has improved performance. The big advantage of a program like this is the advanced reporting you can do, including custom SQL requests. You have to purchase their professional version ($200) to do most of the analytics and custom queries. If Analog is too simple for you, then try the free version of Deep Log Analyzer.

And you can also try Microsoft's own Log Parser, as was the recommended answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157677/a-good-iis-log-viewer-for-large-log-files.
But you will need some extra skills to use it.

Comment: Dead link, Dead project.

Answer (score 2):

**SHORT ANSWER**:

You are correct to question the results; log analysis is not adequate to report actual traffic.

**LONGER ANSWER**:

WebTrends is a great tool for what it delivers.  But as a previous administrator of a WebTrends installation, I found that web logs are notoriously bad at capturing metrics of interest.

For instance, if there exists any caching in your web delivery stack (or on the consumers side-- *I'm shaking my fist at **YOU, AOL**!), then your web logs are instantly non-reflective of your site's actual activity.  This is because log analysis assumes that all user consumption will translate to an HTTP request back to the web server-- and thus having been recorded in the IIS logs.  In the case of a cache, this would not be the case.

In the future if you want more reliable results, you ultimately need to ensure that there exists a way to bust any caching strategy.  The obvious answer is dynamic content.  But if you do not want to rewrite all of your content in such a fashion, just ensure your web traffic analysis uses a dynamic call.

WebTrends actually offers a solution to this problem, called SDC server. This is exactly what Google Analytics offers as well-- it's a javascript call back to the analysis server.

...I could go for days on this.  If you want more specific information, comment back. ;)

***EDIT***: With WebTrends, specifically, it is quite important to configure session tracking beyond their default IP/userAgent configuration.  If your web server assigns a session cookie, you will find this will increase your reliability; especially for differentiating between users which may sit behind the same NAT.

Comment: Yeah, I want them to move to Google Analytics, but that takes effort for them since they didn't setup the URLs in campaign format helpful for Google. The URLs have been printed and they really only have the logs.

Answer (score 2):

What are you wanting to analyze from your logs?  There are a bunch of tools out there - free or paid for - that will go through the logs and spit out a great variety of figures.  Some have real meaning, others are best used with a grain of salt.

What none will show you is "How many people are actually reading my wonderful web pages".  Those that attempt to show "distinct site visitors" or any detailed metrics are at best a rough approximation to an indication of a vague trend...

But for what it's worth, we use [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/).

Comment: We were trying to identify certain URLs (promos) that only exist in the logs because they weren't setup as Google URLs for a campaign. Legacy stuff...

Comment: You will probably find Analog good enough for that - you can filter on directories, file names, and a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: @Ken Ray.  Though, he's already using WebTrends-- which can easily filter on the same criteria.  I'm thinking it's more of a methodology issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have had really good luck with SmarterStats, from [SmarterTools.](http://www.smartertools.com)

Answer (score 0):

There is a logging package for free from MSFT for viewing this information using SQL Reporting Services. Google it.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/tools/logparser/default.mspx

I agree, it's actually quite cool

Answer (score 0):

doing it with the logs is only a good idea if it's internal - I'd use google analytics for anyhing on teh internets

Comment: Thanks Jen, I agree. We only have access to the logs at this point.

Comment: Be aware that google analytics does not capture data for instances where JavaScript fails (either because of bugs or because it's off)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Summary, which is paid for software, for years, and love it.  The cost of updates is getting to me, and paying for an update to just get user agent string updates out of the deal is getting bothersome.  Not that there are not other fixes, I just tend to not need them.

Anyone care to share if they have used Summary compared to analog?

Answer (score 0):

Look at XpoLog log analysis platform for web application servers and web servers log. it a log management and analysis platform that integrate to web servers logs and create reports, provide search and log viewer and also monitor for problems. [XpoLog](http://www.xpolog.com)