# Incorrect site usage report (Sharepoint)

Tags: sharepoint

After restarting "Windows Sharepoint Services Timer" service the "Site usage report" shows only one day of activity (matches the day we restarted the service) while every other day has zeros. I took a look in the "\LOGS\" dir and is plenty of logs with the visit's information for the whole year! Why the usage report ignores it? I think maybe the log file of the day showed could have some kind of mark that the other ones doesn't...

Thanks,
Jorge.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's obvious, but I'll mention it anyway, did you change the option in the dropdown at the top of the report from 'Daily' to 'Month Summary' ?

Alternatively, you could use some form of third party tool to parse the logs from the LOGS\ directory and get some stats out of that. However, that directory will only show you stats from the SharePoint applications, and not stats for visits to the website.

For stats on vists and site activity, you'll be wanting to use the IIS logs, which'll give you much more information. Here are some suggestions for [Log analyzer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356459/web-server-log-analysis-tool)

Cheers